# Facebook connection exception

Tags: java, android

i am trying to connect facebook and get my details in facebook, however when i want to get my name, i get an JSONException with error: ""An active access token must be used to query information about the current user "

i marked the line which it's happen

thanks alot

this is my class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Button logInButton;
    private TextView registerScreen;
    private TextView userText;
    private TextView passwordText;
    private SharedPreferences loginPreferences;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor loginPrefsEditor;
    private Boolean saveLogin;
    private CheckBox saveLoginCheckBox;
    private Button buttonLoginLogout;
    private ShareActionProvider provider;
    private TextView forgotPassword;
    private String userName="";


    private String friendsId="";
    private String friendsName="";
    private List<String> freindsIdList =new ArrayList<String>();

    String FILENAME = "AndroidSSO_data";
    private SharedPreferences mPrefs;
    private Facebook facebook;
    private AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner;
    private static String APP_ID = "xxxxxx" ;


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {



        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
        mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);

        final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 

        buttonLoginLogout=(Button) findViewById(R.id.facebooklog);

        buttonLoginLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    loginToFacebook();
                    getProfileInformation();
                }
        });

    public void loginToFacebook() {
        mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
        long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);

        if (access_token != null) {
            facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
        }

        if (expires != 0) {
            facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
        }

        if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
            facebook.authorize(this,
                    new String[] { "email", "publish_stream" },
                    new DialogListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCancel() {
                            // Function to handle cancel event
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                            // Function to handle complete event
                            // Edit Preferences and update facebook acess_token
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                            editor.putString("access_token",
                                    facebook.getAccessToken());
                            editor.putLong("access_expires",
                                    facebook.getAccessExpires());
                            editor.commit();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(DialogError error) {
                            // Function to handle error

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError fberror) {
                            // Function to handle Facebook errors

                        }

                    });
        }
    }




    public void getProfileInformation() {
        mAsyncRunner.request("me", new RequestListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
                Log.d("Profile", response);
                String json = response;
                try {
                    JSONObject profile = new JSONObject(json);
                    // getting name of the user
                    final String name = profile.getString("name");       //this line i get an JSONException with error: 
                                                                        //"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user "
                    // getting email of the user
                    final String email = profile.getString("email");

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Name: " + name + "\nEmail: " + email, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                    });

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                    Object state) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                    Object state) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
            }
        });
    }

}
```

and here is the logcat:

```
03-18 12:24:32.081: W/System.err(858): org.json.JSONException: No value for name
03-18 12:24:32.131: W/System.err(858):  at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
03-18 12:24:32.131: W/System.err(858):  at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:510)
03-18 12:24:32.150: W/System.err(858):  at com.example.sale.MainActivity$3.onComplete(MainActivity.java:291)
03-18 12:24:32.150: W/System.err(858):  at com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner$2.run(AsyncFacebookRunner.java:276)
```

Comment: plz add json string which u are getting in response form server

Comment: ok   plz check logcat what u are getting in `Log.d("Profile", response);` line in response

Comment: 03-18 12:33:38.075: D/Profile(1156): {"error":{"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.","type":"OAuthException","code":2500}}

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using facebooks new Android 3.0 Facebook library. It has a good tutorial and prebuilt classes to manage states and do Queries. It is much simpler and cleaner than the previous libraries

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/

Look at [Wait till get my id and my freinds id facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471107/wait-till-get-my-id-and-my-freinds-id-facebook/15477132#15477132)
for more information

Comment: i tried to use the newest facebook sdk 3.0, however i got big problem without solution:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471107/wait-till-get-my-id-and-my-freinds-id-facebook  and therefore i want to try another facebook connection (or maybe someone has a solution to my problem?) thanks alot

Comment: i answered the other question, please take a look at it